# Python - Web scraping with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to reproduce a web scraping example with Beautiful Soup. However, I have to say I find it pretty unintuitive, which of course might alse be due to lack of experience. In case anyone could help me with an example I'd appreciate it. I cannot find much relevant information online. I would like to extract the first value (Dornum) of the following website: http://flow.gassco.no/

I only got this far:

```
import requests

page = requests.get("http://flow.gassco.no/")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think, you have to use selenium web driver to bypass term acceptance

Comment: Thanks, I look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use current `requests` module.
You can pass `user-agent` like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}

page = requests.get("http://flow.gassco.no/", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

**EDIT**: To make this version work straightforward you can make a workaround with browser sessions.
You need to pass with `requests.get` a `cookie` that tells the site a session number, where Terms and Conditions are already accepted.

Run this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://flow.gassco.no"
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
action = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser').find('form').get('action') #this gives a "tail" of url whick indicates acceptance of Terms
s.get(url+action)
page = s.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy! Would you still try it with Beautiful Soup?

Comment: yes, your code goes further after `page`. But replace all imports at the top of your script (it's just for sake of proper style=)).

Comment: And add `.text` to `page` or else `soup` won't be created

Comment: btw, I inspected the site a bit and it seems that even with _normal_ user-agent it firstly opens Terms & conditions page and you need to click on 
"accept" to proceed further.
@slesh is right, you need to use `selenium` for at least getting content of page that is hidden by Terms & conds. Then, when you get true page content, you can easily parse in with `Beautifulsoup`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to use `urllib`, `urllib2` first.

Some website shield spiders.

something like:

```
urllib2.request.add_header('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36')
```

Let website think you are Browser, not robot.

Comment: Thanks! Clearly, I need to look into it more.